# Obter mensagem de erro em Post HttpClient

Tags: c#, restful, xamarin-forms, try-catch

Tenho um WCF Service em um servidor cujo serviço está configurado também como WebInvoke:

```
[WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "/work",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

O consumo é realizado com sucesso em um projeto PCL, porém, dependendo das informações que são passadas, o serviço irá tratar e poderá disparar exceções:

Chamada ao serviço:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

A informação de retorno é lida caso `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` não seja verdadeiro, eu obtenho da seguinte forma:

```
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Esse result é uma string de um documento html, contém várias informações, e a mensagem de erro que procuro está na tag body, precisamente dentro de uma div cujo id é igual a "content" (código abaixo)....como eu posso obter somente a mensagem, alguma forma específica?

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'A base de dados Teste não pertence a empresa Alfalagos.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at Custom.OuroNet.Server.WCFCadastre.Cadastro.DoWork(DTOMessageRequest messageRequest)
   at SyncInvokeDoWork(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a biblioteca **HtmlAgilityPack** e utilizando o **XPath** para capturar a div você consegue obter o conteúdo da mesma

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node = document.DocumentNode;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode content = node.Descendants("div").
           Where(div => div.GetAttributeValue("id", string.Empty) == "content").
           FirstOrDefault();
```

Veja funcionando no [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EZQdYW)

**Obs:** É necessário instalar a biblioteca **HtmlAgilityPack** no seu projeto via **NuGet**

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda...porém em Xamarin tive que usar o pacote HtmlAgilityPack-PCL, e nele não contém a opção "SelectNodes".

Comment: Fiz a alteração para o seu caso

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!